# How to get a Wordpress post by Id using query_posts

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to load a post by ID using query_posts, however it always returns an empty array. I get a post Id at random using SQL as follows;

```
$randomProdSql = "SELECT ID FROM `posts` WHERE post_status = 'publish' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,1";
```

I then load that into a variable using;

```
$randomPost = $wpdb->get_var($randomProdSql);
```

This works fine and if I print it out I get an Id. I then call query_posts like this;

```
$args = array(
    'p' => $randomPost
);

$posts = query_posts($args);
```

I would now expect the $posts variable to contain the post.. however, if I call;

```
print_r($args);
print_r($posts);
```

I get:

```
Array
(
    [p] => 778
)
Array
(
)
```

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update your code as below:

```
query_posts('p='.'"$randomPost"');
```

Also, rather using the query_posts() method to get a single post, you can use get_post() method.

```
$my_post = get_post($randomPost);
echo $my_post->post_title;
```

Comment: Thanks! Using query_posts as you suggested still did not work, but switching to use get_post did.

Comment: `p` will only get you id's of the post type `post` only. If you want to get id's of any other post type you have to define post-type in attributes.

Answer (score 0):

As per your code, you shared you want post id's in random manner. The following code will get the post id's for you in random manner.

By using `post_per_page` you can control the number of posts returned in result. Also, `fields` will force the query to return id's of posts. However, in case you want to retrieve any other field also please remove it from here. As, it only supports id field only.

For details please refer to this [link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query):

```
<?php 
    $args = array(
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'orderby' => 'rand',
        'fields' => 'ids',
        'posts_per_page' => '1'
    );

    $posts = query_posts($args);
?>
```

Comment: Please elaborate how and why your code fragment supposedly solves the asked questions. Thank you.